# How to format schema.org correctly with product sold by length?

Tags: schema.org

I have a product which is sold by the length in 0.25-yard increments. 1 qty is equal to 0.25

While with Google Shopping Feed it was fairy easy to do with [unit_pricing_measure](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324455?hl=en) and [unit_pricing_base_measure](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6324490?hl=en):

```
<price>5 USD</price>
<unit_pricing_measure>0.25 yd</unit_pricing_measure>
<unit_pricing_base_measure>1 yd</unit_pricing_base_measure>
```

I expect above code to result in: "$20 per yard"

I cannot figure out how to replicate this in Schema.org. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it could be something and repeat like this:

```js
{
  "@context":"https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "name":"The name",
  "description":"zzzzz",
  "offers": {
      "@type": "Offer",
      "priceSpecification": {
        "@type":"UnitPriceSpecification",
        "price":"20",
        "priceCurrency":"USD",
        "referenceQuantity":{
          "@type":"QuantitativeValue",
          "name":"yard",
          "value":"1",
          "unitText":"yard",
          "unitCode":"YRD",
          "sameAs":"http://www.unece.org/fileadmin/DAM/cefact/recommendations/bkup_htm/add2h.htm"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

The following chain is used here: **Product** => **Offer** => **priceSpecification** => **UnitPriceSpecification** => **referenceQuantity** => **QuantitativeValue**. 
Note that the property **sameAs** with url used here is to identify.